# Why can't get files from Sharepoint 2013 Library Folder using REST API

Tags: list, rest, file, sharepoint, get

I am trying to get a list of files from a SharePoint Library using REST api.
To do so I'm using this query :

```
https://[Site]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('[Folder]')?$expand=Files,Folders
```

SharePoint give me the following json :

```
{
  "d": {
    "__metadata": {
      "id": "https://[Site]/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('[Folder]')",
      "uri": "https://[Site]/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('[Folder]')",
      "type": "SP.Folder"
    },
    "Files": { "results": [] },
    "ListItemAllFields": { "__deferred": { "uri": "https://[Site]/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('[Folder]')/ListItemAllFields" } },
    "ParentFolder": { "__deferred": { "uri": "https://[Site]/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('[Folder]')/ParentFolder" } },
    "Properties": { "__deferred": { "uri": "https://[Site]/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('[Folder]')/Properties" } },
    "StorageMetrics": { "__deferred": { "uri": "https://[Site]/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('[Folder]')/StorageMetrics" } },
    "Folders": { "results": [] },
    "Exists": true,
    "IsWOPIEnabled": false,
    "ItemCount": 4,
    "Name": "TEST",
    "ProgID": null,
    "ServerRelativeUrl": "[Folder]",
    "TimeCreated": "2016-12-01T10:50:22Z",
    "TimeLastModified": "2016-12-21T10:14:43Z",
    "UniqueId": "144967f1-512f-4180-b4a8-be8d0bfe90d9",
    "WelcomePage": ""
  }
}
```

As you can see, there are 4 Items in this folder (look at the 'ItemCount' property) but empty results appear in the 'Files' field nor 'Folders' field.

I know that there are really 4 files in this folder, because i can see them directly on the web site using the same login and password used by the REST API query.

I also try this query :

```
https://[Site]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('[Folder]')/Files
```

the answer is

```
{"d":{"results":[]}}
```

Is there any specials autorisations or things to know for listing Files and Folders from REST api ?

Comment: Hello I am facing this same issue right now. How did you solve yours?

Answer (score -4):

Please use API below :

```
https://sites.sharepoint.com/sites/test/forms/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/site or subsite URL/name Document List/name of folder')/Files
```

If the JSON shows `{"d":{"results":[]}}`, it means the folder you selected is empty.